# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a music bot for discord and I finish the code and tried to run it and when I run the play command it simply says this.

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "play" is not found
```

Here's my code.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

TOKEN = "Token here"
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "s ");

@bot.event
    async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), id=794444804607574026)
    await channel.connect()

 async def play(ctx, url):
     player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
     player.start()

 bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added `@bot.command(name="play")` above the play function

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

TOKEN = "Token here"
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "s ");

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = discord.utils.get(bot.get_all_channels(), id=794444804607574026)
    await channel.connect()
 
 @bot.command(name="play")
 async def play(ctx, url):
     player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
     player.start()

 bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

before

```py
async def play(ctx, url):
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

after

```py
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

Comment: first join to VC

Comment: im in the vc its just when i run the play command nothing seems to happen. there is nothing in the console either. @Delta

Comment: nothing seems to happen when i run the play command @Delta

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code:

**main.py**

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

import discord
import os
import youtube_dl

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="s")

@bot.event
async def on_ready()
    print("{0.user} is online".format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

**.env**

```
TOKEN=<paste your token here>
```

Hope it’s helped you (: